# Reading from File Java OOP Aggregation

Tags: java, oop, aggregation

Can someone help me? I don't know how to read from a text file in Java.
I have a class Neighbourhood (index, ArrayList)and a class Street(name, numberOfPeople). A neighbourhood can have more streets. (arraylist of streets).
I don't know how to write in a file more neighbourhoods (each with their streets) and how to read from it.
I'm really sorry, I am a beginner in java.

This is how I add neighbourhoods manually, but I have to do it from a file.

```
        ArrayList<Neighbourhood> neighbourhoods = new ArrayList<Neighbourhood>();

        ArrayList<Street> streets1 = new ArrayList<Street>();
        streets1.add(new Street("Panselelor", 200));
        streets1.add(new Street("Mihai Viteazul", 150));

        ArrayList<Street> streets2 = new ArrayList<Street>();
        streets2.add(new Street("Lunga", 80));
        streets2.add(new Street("15 noiembrie", 60));

        neighbourhoods.add(new Neighbourhood(115, streets1));
        neighbourhoods.add(new Neighbourhood(116, streets2));
```

Can you help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Search on the web about the classes PrintWriter and BufferedReader.

Comment: What does the "aggregation" tag mean here? I see no aggregation.

Comment: What is the structure/format of the text file with the data?  Is it a JSON file, CSV or just a plain text? How is the information about neighborhoods and streets is stored?  Please edit your question and add this information.